# ActiveMQ topic send automatically

Tags: automation, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have some subscribers that they are listening to "mytopic"...I send message to them by browser UI just like attached image
but now I want to do this work in code environment 
what should I do and whats that code and methods?

[-----> attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9M2R.png)

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of packages for communicating with a server. Do you have any experience in coding? If so, use that language.

Comment: Yes...please read the title -- > "ActiveMQ topic send automatically
"

Answer (score 1):

You should have mentioned what programming language you want to use. Every language may offer a different API and specification.

In case of using Java, you can simply program according to the JMS specification 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html

Also, the Apache ActiveMQ installation comes with a few examples that you can use as a reference. E.g. see 
examples/openwire/swissarmy/src/TopicPublisher.java

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [ActiveMQ Protocols](http://activemq.apache.org/protocols.html) - for example you can use the  [ActiveMQ REST API](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) to POST messages to the topic or use [JMS](http://activemq.apache.org/jms.html).

Then you can look at how to use these from a "client" (presumably your central server) perspective.

For REST from Java (say) you could look at [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)